# How to convert special characters to UTF-8?

Tags: perl

When I extract data from a MySQL database, some of the output have special characters,
when opened in e.g. emacs it decodes to `\240` and `\346`.

When shown in an UTF-8 terminal, the special characters is shown as `�`

So the used encoding seams to only use 1 byte per character.

I can e.g. see that `\346` should be `æ`.

**Question**

Does Perl have a module that can encode these special characters to UTF-8?

Comment: http://blog.jonnay.net/archives/820-Emacs-and-UTF-8-Encoding.html ?

Comment: The question is not about emacs. I would like Perl to encode the content to UTF-8.

Comment: have you set up the terminal to show utf-8?

Comment: You likely just need to use encode/decode.  See : http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunitut.html

Comment: @Joe that solved the problem =) If you post that, when I will accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Encode::decode` to decode your data from whatever encoding it's in to Perl's internal format.

Then, when writing the data out to a file, set the `'utf8'` layer to make the data be written in UTF-8.

```
use Encode;

my $data_from_database = ...;

my $perl_data = decode('ISO-8859-1', $data_from_database);

binmode STDOUT, ':utf8';

print $perl_data;
```